# Strange behavior with ISNULL() in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that is combining multiple segments of a persons name. This isn't anything new.

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName FROM MyTable
```

I then tried to add the middle initial to this and I came up with the following

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + ISNULL(MiddingInitial + ' ', '') + LastName AS FullName FROM MyTable
```

This appears to work, but during my testing of `ISNULL()`, I came across an odd behavior. I'm aware that `NULL + 'any string'` resolves to `NULL`. However this was just plain odd...

Here's my code, and what I get out as a result...

```
print '''' + isnull(null + 'Any String','Results in null') + ''''
print '''' + isnull(null + 'Any','Results in null') + ''''
print '''' + isnull(null + 'A','Results in null') + ''''
print '''' + isnull(null + '','Results in null') + ''''
/*
'Results in '
'Resu'
'Re'
'Re'
*/
```

Any idea of why this behavior occurs? Does it do the same for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes down to the datatypes you're working with and the behavior of the `ISNULL` function. Let's look at one example:

```
null + 'Any String'
```

The above fits perfectly into a `varchar(11)` datatype. The `NULL` (which is really just the result of `char(0)` and has length 1) and a regular 10-character string concatenated together makes for 11 characters total. The replacement string -- the second parameter to your `ISNULL` function -- is going to be forced to fit into a `varchar(11)`, so it is truncated to 11 characters.

The pattern repeats for the remaining items, with a special case for the empty string.

If you don't want this to happen, use `COALESCE`, which instead of taking the datatype of the first item in the list, it uses data type precedence. A `varchar(15)` takes precedence over a `varchar(11)`, so you will get the full replacement string:

```
print '''' + coalesce(null + 'Any String','Results in null') + ''''
print '''' + coalesce(null + 'Any','Results in null') + ''''
print '''' + coalesce(null + 'A','Results in null') + ''''
print '''' + coalesce(null + '','Results in null') + ''''
/*
'Results in null'
'Results in null'
'Results in null'
'Results in null'
*/
```

Comment: That's actually pretty cool. Thanks for the answer on this one!